# Is disabling updates really the only way to stop Firefox's "Restart required" on opening a new tab?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox-quantum

Firefox's (seemingly new in 63.0 but maybe I've been lucky until now) background/running updates are causing me problems as I suddenly get "Restart Required" when I open a new tab.  FF claims it will reload tabs, but (1) only when I click on them, so I don't notice that I'm no longer getting notifications from ones I haven't clicked on, and (2) Office365 really doesn't play nice  when you restart, and that's work, by definition.

So what I want to do is disable **background** updating.  But which of the 30-40 barely-documented options in about:config does that? Does any of them?

This is so problematic that I'll probably just disable all FF updates if I have to, to avoid losing work, by blocking the update server if it comes to it.  After all, I've never lost anything due to running an old version (and I have been stuck on old versions for a long time in the past) but I have lost work due to this option.

But surely there's an actual solution.  Surely?

Comment: If you can restart FF anytime regardless of the prompt, how is this a problem?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia it's a problem because the first I know it's updated is when I can't open new tabs in the middle of a piece of work.  I use FF because it's stable; it simply doesn't crash on me. If I lose a half-written email reply I've spend half an hour carefully crafting, because the restarted tab loaded an old draft and I didn't think copy-paste the text into an editor, that's a problem.

Comment: You mean FF version up updates, right? Which Ubuntu OS version, and why is Firefox trying to update itself? On Ubuntu 16.04 anyway, updating Firefox should be through the Software Updater.

Comment: @user3169 18.04, and FF was  installed via Ubuntu, so I'm not sure what's going on I know searching for `update` on `about:config` returns lots of mozilla.org URLs similar to my Windows system in work (e.g. app.update.url), so maybe if I break those, I can see if it gets updated by the OS, and if so whether that works sensibly.

Comment: I can't say for sure because on my Ubuntu system I am using 52esr for extension compatibility reasons, though I'll probably switch soon. But is there a "Firefox Updates" section in your FF Preferences? 52esr doesn't have one, unlike any Windows version. If not, then FF isn't doing it and I would think something else is going on. Could it be Office 365, some other webapp or extension updating? Adding a screenshot of some on-screen dialog might help to ID the issue.

Comment: AFAIK you should only update FF when available in Software Updater, unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @user3169 I agree, and in over 10 years of using various flavours of Linux with Firefox updating using software updater has been the standard behaviour, with no problems. I recently installed 18.04 so don't know if anything changed there, but it seems to have been the update from 62.x to 63.0 that started to be the issue. Software updater had run earlier in the day, and I'd shut right down in between, so it really seems like FF's updater. IIRC there's exactly one update option in FF preferences, and it's not one to turn them off, or update only when the user wants. Less than before I think

Comment: [This comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/9s78fh/sick_of_getting_restart_required/e8mtfj0/) on reddit sheds some light on what's going on behind the scenes. If your distro updates firefox in the background, there is a mismatch between files on disk and the running instance. I believe a solution might be to install firefox from its .deb installer or snap.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu (and many other Debian-based Linux distros), automatic Firefox updates are handled through `unattended-upgrades`, part of the APT system. This is totally outside Firefox's control, so as you probably suspect, `about:config` won't help you here.

There are other resources out there on how to pin a package to a specific version:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package
However, this prevents updates from being installed at all, even when you manually run `apt-get upgrade`. Probably not what you want.

Another option is to disable automatic security updates altogether. This can be done in the "Software & Updates" application (`software-properties-gtk`) under the "Updates" tab. If you manually upgrade very frequently, maybe that's okay, but generally, there is no need for this, because...

**You can configure `unattended-upgrades` to skip specific packages relatively easily:**

Edit the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` and find the `Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist` section. Add a line to block any package starting with `firefox`:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
    // Some existing comments, maybe some other stuff

    // ADD THIS LINE:
    "firefox";
};
```

Now, APT will not update Firefox without your knowledge, but you can still manually upgrade when convenient, and other security upgrades won't be impacted.

**For completeness, when Firefox handles its own upgrades:**

This does not really apply to this question, since Firefox's built-in update mechanism doesn't suffer from the problem described (where new tabs refuse to work until Firefox is restarted). But for the sake of completeness, on systems where Firefox handles its own updates (e.g. Windows), here's the `about:config` options to control it:

- `app.update.enabled` - When set to `true`, Firefox checks for updates automatically. When set to `false`, it does not. The default is `true`.
- `app.update.auto` - When set to `true`, updates are automatically downloaded and installed when available. When set to `false`, Firefox asks the user what to do when an update is available. The default is `true`. (This assumes `app.update.enabled` is `true`, because otherwise, it won't check if updates are available at all.)

These entries may or may not exist on your system. If not, Firefox will use the default unless you create them.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution - or at least a partial solution.

You can change the way Firefox is installed.  It sounds like you have it installed through a package manager.  If that is the case, then the package manager will *also* handle the *update*s for Firefox, which (generally) means it will update even when Firefox is running.

If you [install Firefox without using a package manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux) then it should use its own update feature instead.  Once you've installed this way, you may still want to fiddle with Firefox's **about:config** to get (as close as possible) to the exact update behavior you want.
Note that if you don't change the update method before changing **about:config**, you may have unexpected results (but I can't speak to the details on that).

Answer (score 1):

I also find this feature quite intrusive, actually reminding me of MS Windows 15 minutes mandatory coffee break when login to the computer for an urgent matter, even though FF's way is far less painfull.

Comparing FF about:config on Ubuntu where it forces reload and on Manjaro where it doesn't (at least for me), I found an interesting key:

```
app.update.mode
```

It is set to 1 on Manjaro while it is unset (maybe hence defaulting to 0) on Ubuntu.

Full reference is available at https://kb.mozillazine.org/App.update.mode

The drawback is that FF updates will be taken care of by system upgrades, not by FF itself.

I've just created the key as numeric with a value of 1 on Ubuntu.

I might not be able to figure out if it properly works prior next few releases.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem :(
Firefox randomly prompts to restart as least every week (and crashes after that, all website tabs gone). For the reason of using many private tabs its a small catastrophe.
Installed via apt. Apt is setup to not updating anything automatically, setup via unattended-upgrades.
-> Ubuntu 20 LTS. Firefox 100.0.2.
Unfortunately firefox does not have suggested options in config:about. So I cannot disable it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Would you mind to give me some hints?
Main problem: Firefox crashes every week at least one time. Then it gives info to be crashed and asks for restart because of updates.
Seconds problem regarding previous answers: Firefox was installed via apt and apt does not update anything by unattended-updates as per config file.
Third problem regarding previous answers: This Firefox version doesn't know options like auto update via about:config.

Better?

Comment: How can I write new lines?

Comment: @kasper2083 Community is a bot, it doesn't know how to answer you. But it commented because you've posted in the answers section for something that's not an answer. If you are having trouble and you think it's a different issue than this, you should post a new question, but be sure to add specific details about what you've tried and why the answers already here didn't work.